# Update DS-160 Number for my Family

Tags: visas

i have forgot to submit my ds160, it is automatically deleted after 30 days
Now i must  créate an other and update my profile for me it is possible.
But i can't update the ds160 numbers of my familly
it IS very urgent because our appointment is for 24-10-2022
thank you for your help

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: @Traveller I think they're trying to apply for a US Visa and have an interview scheduled, but their application (DS-160) has expired, and if they miss the interview it may take over a year to find another slot.

Comment: @Traveller I think the OP cannot update her family's individual files with the OP's new DS-160 number. The OP's wording is very difficult to parse.

Comment: my question is how i can update the ds 160 number of my family, to update the Appointment Confirmation?

Comment: Can you please let us know how you solved the issue? We are also having the same issue.
Thanks
Niv